# Removing and adding children of a physics node

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, children, spritebuilder

I am writing a Cocos2d V3, chipmunk game, which involves loading in a ccbfile - a node -, and initializing its class, called redLight. I then add that ccbfile with a certain number of children to an overarching level node,  creat an array of redlight's, and then remove them as children of itself, and add them as children of the overarching level node.

**When I remove a node and add it to another parent inside a physics body, its physics node's position is not transformed**

I need to do this in order to make the redLight instance aware of its children, but add them to its parent so that any future positional calculations do not need to involve transforming the position of the children in its parent node (redLight) to its position in the overarching level node.

The problem I am facing is that when I execute the following code, under debug draw, the light's positions are transformed to the overarching level node, but the physics bodies are not. The character is supposed to collide with the physics bodies and then execute an action, but since the physicsbodies don't transform their position, nothing useful happens.
Here is my code:
for (int i = 0; i < [redLights count]; i++) {

```
    lightSource *switchLight = [redLights objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint diffPos = ccpAdd(switchLight.position, self.position);
    [self removeChild:switchLight cleanup:NO];
    switchLight.physicsBody = nil;
    switchLight.position = diffPos;
//switchLight.physicsBody.absolutePosition = switchLight.position;
    switchLight.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:[switchLight          radius] andCenter:switchLight.position];
    switchLight.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
    [[[gameData sharedData].GamePlayNode level] addChild:switchLight];

    switchLight.physicsBody.collisionType = @"redLight";
//switchLight.physicsBody.absolutePosition = switchLight.position;
      }
```

#### I would appreciate help with this.

[image: With debug draw]

Of course, closer to release date, I will completely update the graphics and make the UX more remarkable with more interactivity, but now, I am focusing on the core gameplay
[image: This is without debug draw.]

Comment: You need to post the related code, otherwise no one can tell whether you're doing it incorrectly somehow. Also mention the version of cocos2d used.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had. I appreciate very much your reminder

Answer (score 0):

Transforms of `CCNodes` with physics bodies in Cocos2D 3.x are relative to the `CCPhysicsNode` not relative to the parent node (https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/issues/570). This means there is no real alternative to setting the absolute position of the physics objects manually. Another option to move `CCNodes` with physics together with their parent would be using physics joints but that does not seem the right solution for this problem.

Comment: Hi Ben, what a coincidence that you should answer my question because I am at MGWU NYC, and discussed this problem with Dion. In the end, instead of using transformations, I implemented another few methods which take all sprites with a  certain name, and creates a red-light class. Instead of iterating through its children and adding those to a light beams array, this new version of the red-light class iterates through an array passed to it by Gameplay, and creates new iterations of the class for each unique sprite name;